# Vagrant unable to find virtualbox version

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, vagrant

I try to use vagrant for a project. Everytime I try to run a command, the following message is show:

> Vagrant failed to initialize at a very early stage:

> Vagrant detected that VirtualBox appears installed on your system,
> but calls to detect the version are returning empty. This is often
> indicative of installation issues with VirtualBox. Please verify
> that VirtualBox is properly installed. As a final verification,
> please run the following command manually and verify a version is
> outputted:

> C:/Program Files/Oracle/VirtualBox/VBoxManage.exe --version

If I try the following command on Git Bash:

`C:/Program\ Files/Oracle/VirtualBox/VBoxManage.exe --version`

There is no version in the output.

However, if I try to run this commande in powershell,

`& "C:/Program Files/Oracle/VirtualBox/VBoxManage.exe" --version`

The version is correctly printed. The few occurence of this bug that I found online didn't provide a way to fix my issue. I've tried to activate Hyper-V and it appear that I can run one single vagrant command. The next one fallback to the previous error message.

The exact same process with the exact same version of both Vagrant and VirtualBox work for my team mates and I'm currently clueless about why it fail on my computer.
If someone as any idea over the cause of such error, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It’s probably a system PATH variable issue

Comment: @Ramhound, I've rebooted my system so I'm sure the PATH is the same everywhere. Both Vagrant and VirtualBox env var are correctly set and I call VirtualBox with its fullpath . What make you think of a problem with the PATH?

Comment: Because you indicated it worked on one system and not the other

Comment: @Ramhound seems fair but it finds VirtualBox and its version is not part of an env var.

Comment: So what is different between your system and the working system?